# How to properly implement an association of two models/objects via the seeds.rb in Rails?

Tags: associations, has-many, belongs-to, seed, model-associations

So, here is the deal: I have two models, a Player and a Team. Every team has_many players and every player belongs_to a team. The code (omitting a few unnecessary atributes from the player model):

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :points, :rank
  has_many :players

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age, :pos, :team
  belongs_to :team
```

I am using seeds.rb to create a few teams and a bunch of players and then I try to put players into teams (that is, I try to actually implement the "has_many" and "belongs_to" associations). The code:

```
rndm = rand(1..10) #random number of teams

rndm.each do |i| #create rndm teams
  i = i.to_s
  Team.create(name: 'Team'+i, points: 0, ranking: 0)
end

for i in 1..rndm*22 do #create rndm*22 players (ideally 22 for each team)
  i = i.to_s
  Player.create(name: 'Player'+i, age: rand(15..35), 
                pos: 'Not specified', team: Team.find(rand(1..rndm)))
end
```

Now, the above code creates the teams and the players just fine. However, it does not associate players with teams. It does not associate them with a team at all. That is, when I type "@player = Player.find(1)" and "@player.team" in the rails console all I get is "=> nil". BUT, when I specify the team myself (still in the console) by typing "@player.team = Team.find(1)", the association is achieved just fine (resulting in the "player.team" argument to return the details for the team with team id: 1).

I assume I have to modify the Player controller or something like that? If so, what's different when I associate the two models from the console rather than from the seeds.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you're seeding scheme to work,  you'd have to be setting team_id:  instead of :team when you create the Player.

```
for i in 1..rndm*22 do #create rndm*22 players (ideally 22 for each team)
  i = i.to_s
  Player.create(name: 'Player'+i, age: rand(15..35), 
            pos: 'Not specified', team_id: Team.find(rand(1..rndm))).id
end
```

Comment: There is no "team_id" attribute though, neither in the Team model nor in the Player one. Do I have to add it to both then? (I am getting a "unknown attribute: team_id" when I run rake db:seed now)

Comment: If Player belongs to Team,  players table would need a team_id attribute.

Comment: I had to also manually change the schema.rb and XYZ_create_users.rb files so the associations work. Thanks for the directions!

Comment: Next time,  use 'rails g migration add_team_id_to_player',  that will generate a new migration file,  edit that file to add the team_id attribute,  then run 'rake db:migrate',  that will add the attribute AND update your schema file.